# it is possible to schedule tasks for a long time with node-schedule and CloudFuntions Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to schedule certain daily tasks, example payment notifications, payments and other things. My question is if through Cloud Functions I can get this.

An example of a task I need, is to make a daily payment, for 8 months, from Monday to Friday.

Activation of this I can do with a Cloud Function and the payment schedule I want to implement node-schedule. The main reason is because I use Cloud Firestore and it comes in handy in the project to implement the functions of the cloud and the database.

That's why I open the post, to know if it is possible for the Cloud Function to load these tasks in memory and execute them when node-schedule requires it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions have a maximum execution time of 9 minutes, and you are billed for CPU and memory usage the entire time an instance is running. Using an in-process scheduler like `node-schedule` isn't possible for long time periods and isn't generally recommended even for shorter ones due to the cost involved.

Instead, you can use [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to define an arbitrary cron-like repeating job that will execute a function on a set schedule. It should be very possible to establish a "Mon-Fri daily payment" in such a scheduled function.